# Count specific rows in field using ArcGIS Field Calculator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator

I got 1 buffer and 1 point shape data. I want to spatially join the buffers with points (input:buffers, join:points). There is a point_type field in the point layer. I want that information as a count.

For example, if there are 20 of '2020'(point_type), 10 of '2021'(point type) data in a buffer, i need to know that.

Comment: Using ArcMap, QGIS, Python, or JavaScript? In ArcMap the field Calculator is for setting values not counting. In ArcMap after a spatial Join you would summarize on your field. But what are you using?

Comment: Qgis and Arcmap @BillChappell

Answer (score 2):

This may work well enough, In ArcMap right click on point layer, join, spatial join,

1. the polygon layer.
2. joining polygons to points. it falls inside,
3. give it a new shape name

   - hit Ok.

Open the new point shape, it has the values of the point and the values from the poly.  In my case the points have a verified Y or N, and the polys have a name, so I just add a new field Text type, and using the field calculator, calc it's value to be (verified & "-" & Name) this gives me a field that has "Y-Monroe", "N-Monroe", "Y-Pike", etc.. right click on this new field, summarize. It should give you a table that has a count of each type.